# In R, how do you extract and combine strings from data frame columns into a new list?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from which I am able to access the strings I've stored in various columns. For instance, adults$IDone and adults$IDtwo each produces all of the strings for each of those columns. However, when I try to combine those two sets of strings c(adults$IDone, adults$IDtwo) I get back numbers instead of the stored strings. I feel I must be completely misunderstanding something about how data frames work... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: See Brandon's answer below. If you don't want your strings to be treated as factors in your data frame, use the appropriate argument to prevent it when creating/reading the data frame. For example when using the ubiquitous read.table function, give an extra stringsAsFactors=F argument

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining that. I'm a bit confused about the use of having things stored as factors at all.. I suppose I need to read up on that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adults$IDone` and the other variable are factors. When you try to concatenate them with `c()` you get back their numeric representations. This is a common beginners problem.

You need to wrap them in as.character() to get your desired output.

```
c(as.character(adults$IDone), as.character(adults$IDtwo))
```

Comment: Thanks! You're correct, I am a beginner. This was very helpful, thank you.